# Nativescript RadListView not binding to source property

Tags: telerik, observable, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am trying to implement {N} telerik's UI RadListView. [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/getting-started) is their getting started guide, which I followed as a reference.

I have setup the following XML layout :

> list.xml

```
<StackLayout loaded="loaded" xmlns:lv="nativescript-telerik-ui/listview" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <lv:RadListView items="{{ rankingsArray }}">
        <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
            <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="vertical"/>
        </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
    </lv:RadListView>
    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" class="sl_ranking">
            <Label text="{{ name }}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Basically I am binding the list view to a `rankingsArray` containing child elements which have a `name` property.

In fact here is how I do the binding :

> list.js
>   var HashtagList = require("~/viewmodels/HashtagsList");

```
exports.loaded = function(args){
    var hashtagList = new HashtagList();
    var profile = args.object;
    profile.bindingContext = hashtagList;
}
```

HashtagList is class defined as :

```
var Hashtag = require("~/classes/Hashtag");
var ObservableModule = require("data/observable-array");
class HashtagList{
    constructor(){
    }
    get rankingsArray(){

        if(!this._list){
            this._list = new ObservableModule.ObservableArray();
            this._list.push(new Hashtag("#pizzawithfriends"));
            this._list.push(new Hashtag("#funky"));
        }

        return this._list;
    }
}
module.exports = HashtagList;
```

As you can see any `HashtagList` object has a public `rankingsArray` property which returns an `observable array` of `Hashtag` objects.
Here is the definition of the `Hashtag` object:

> hashtag.js

```
"use strict";
var Hashtag = function(name){
    var _name = name;
    //====== NAME GETTER & SETTER ======//
    Object.defineProperty(this,"name",{
        get : function(){
            return _name;
        },
        set : function(value){
            _name = value;
        }
    })
}

module.exports = Hashtag;
```

The problem is that for some reason I get the following error :

```
Binding: Property: 'name' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'name'
```

and  nothing appears on the screen.
This is weird because if I can access `HashtagList.rankingsArray.getItem(0).name` without problems.
What is causing this behavior?

Comment: I just skimmed the code, should you be creating a new instance of HashTagList() in the loaded event twice?

Comment: @BradMartin nope sorry , I copied the code wrong. Only one instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I closed the `label` tag in the wrong way...

> WRONG WAY

```
<lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" class="sl_ranking">
            <Label text="{{ name }}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
```

> RIGHT WAY

```
 <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" class="sl_ranking">
                **<Label text="{{ name }}" />**
            </StackLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
```